# Very strange behavior of 3rd-party Django addons

Tags: django

After I installed django_tinymce and django-filebrowser I noticed that folders

> \venv\Lib\site-packages\django_tinymce-1.5.1b2-py2.6.egg\

and

> \venv\Lib\site-packages\django_filebrowser-3.5.0-py2.6.egg\

contain copies of my django project. What is the reason for such an awful behavior of these libraries? Is this common practice?

Comment: What's the location of your virtual environment?

Comment: D:\blizzard\Projects\Python\Web\moz455\venv

Comment: I haven't heard of that before. Does it only happy with those two eggs or with any installed lib?

Comment: So far only with them. But I haven't installed many libraries.

Comment: What happens if you create your env in a location outside your django project?

Comment: Then these libraries work as expected. Seems it's the right answer to the question.